# global dimension II

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory

Suppose we are given finite dimensional semisimple $k$-algebras $A_1,..., A_r$. now we consider the matrix algebra$A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & M_{1,2} & \dots  & M_{1,r}      \\
0 & A_2  & \dots  & M_{2,r}    \\
\vdots & 0  & \ddots & \vdots \\
0  & \dots & 0  & A_r
\end{pmatrix}$
with finitely generated bimodules $M_{i,j}$. Suppose $A=\mathrm{End}(\mathcal{T})$, for some $G$-equivariant tilting bundle on some smooth projective variety $X$ over a field $k$ of characteristic zero on which $G$ acts. One has $\mathrm{gldim}(A)$ is finite. Furthermoe suppose we are given a linearly reductive group $G$ acting on $X$. Do we have $\mathrm{gldim}(\mathrm{End}_G(\mathcal{T}))<\infty$?

Comment: What is the difference between this and your previous question?

Comment: $G$ is an algebraic group and linearly reductive and not supposed to be finite.